# image gallery select with description when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a gallery with thumbnails so when you click a thumbnail it will appear on the top *make it big* with different description. Image shows correctly but I don't know how to show the 'span' to the right.

Can anyone make this js better.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/2/

```
$(function(){
    $("#big-image img:eq(0)").nextAll().hide();
    $(".small-images img").click(function(e){
        var index = $(this).index();
        $("#big-image img").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is the span content ?

Comment: Oh well I just put 1 span which is in the big-image div.

Answer (score 1):

Just like: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qhdaz/819/):

```
<div id="big-image">
    <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/"><span>Image One</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/fashion/1/"><span>Image Two</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city/1/"><span>Image Three</span></p>
</div>
```

And JS: `$("#big-image p").eq(index).show().siblings().hide();`